# Declare type of struct field to be the same type as the struct itself in Julia

Tags: performance, struct, types, julia, field

If I define a struct in Julia, is it possible to declare the type of one of its fields to be of the same type as the struct itself? For example, I want to define a struct `NodeStruct` with two fields, `data` and `next` where `data` is some standard type (e.g. `AbstractFloat`) and `next` is `NodeStruct` type or `nothing`. Consider this example code which gives an error `LoadError: UndefVarError: NodeStruct not defined`.

```
import Base.@kwdef

@kwdef mutable struct NodeStruct{A<:AbstractFloat, B<:Union{NodeStruct, Nothing}}
    data ::A
    next ::B
end
```

Is it possible to do this somehow? I would like to be able to do this parametrically as the [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-fields-with-abstract-type) suggest this and computation time is very important to me. I could not find any information in the documentation on [types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/) or [constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/) that resolves this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that elements of your structure a concrete type this just will be:

```
@kwdef mutable struct NodeStruct{A<:AbstractFloat}
    data ::A
    next ::Union{NodeStruct, Nothing}
end
```

And now you just use it

```
julia> NodeStruct(3.5, nothing)
NodeStruct{Float64}(3.5, nothing)
```

If you need slightly more abstract structure you can do:

```
abstract type AbstractNS end

@kwdef mutable struct NodeStruct2{A<:AbstractFloat, B<:AbstractNS} <: AbstractNS
    data ::A
    next ::Union{Nothing, B}
end
```

When creating the root for this abstract structure you need to provide the type:

```
julia> root = NodeStruct2{Float64, NodeStruct2}(3.5, nothing)
NodeStruct2{Float64, NodeStruct2}(3.5, nothing)
```

However for leaves it will just work:

```
julia> leaf = NodeStruct2(5.6, root)
NodeStruct2{Float64, NodeStruct2{Float64, NodeStruct2}}(5.6, NodeStruct2{Float64, NodeStruct2}(3.5, nothing))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, defining the struct in this way seems to present another issue. If I replace my struct definition with the one you wrote (and then restart Julia), then run the code, it works the first time, but then all successive attempts to run the code defining this struct give `LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant NodeStruct`. This does not normally happen with normal struct definitions. For clarity, I'm aware that this error also happens if you change a struct definition without restarting Julia, but in this case that is not the issue.

Comment: "all successive attempts to run the code" - you can define a `struct` only once. Later definitions must be under a different name or you need to restart Julia.

Comment: Sorry, allow me to elaborate a little. Normally, if I define a struct in a file e.g. MyStruct.jl and then I make another file NewFile.jl which starts with `include("MyStruct.jl")`, then I can normally run the NewFile.jl as many times as I want without restarting Julia. However, if I try to declare a field in NodeStruct using e.g. `next ::NodeStruct` or `next ::Union{NodeStruct, Nothing}`, then I can only run NewFile.jl once without restarting Julia. I imagine that this is not intended behavior? Thank you.

Comment: On my machine (Julia 1.6.0 RC1) when I do not change the definition I can run this many times. This seems to be a subject for a separate question.

Comment: For the record, I was using Julia 1.3.1 when it wasn't working and I just updated to Julia 1.6.0 RC1 and now it works, so that fixes that issue. Thank you.